# Is there a way to render a code/verbatim text with a grey background in orgmode markup language?

Tags: org-mode, markup

In markdown, when I put a text between two backsticks, the text will be rendered `text` with a grey background. I want to find a similar markup in orgmode, especially when it can be exported to other format and rendered correctly (ex: in HTML it would be `<code>text</code>`). The only answer that I found would be using the double `=` (=code=) or double `~` (~verbatim~). But when I tried exporting it to HTML, it's only rendered with verbatim text without the grey background.

It seems to be a very basic question and I've been looking around other Q&A but it doesn't seem to be mentionned anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Org mode `=this is code=` construct is exported to HTML as `<code>this is code</code>` so you can use CSS to do whatever you want with that. E.g. try

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>code {background-color: #ff0000}</style>

* Foo
This =code should have a red background=.
```

This should work for HTML. Not sure whether you can do something generic that will work with any export that supports color.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Effectively, since I still a newbie about HTML coding, it didn't occur me to that I need to customize CSS to display this syntax the way I always see.